# Image processing: Recognise multiple instances of the same objects in an image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sift, surf, ransac

I am working on a project where I have to recognize objects in a grocery shells. You can see the sample image below:

[image: Example Image]

I need to find what products exists in an image. The example of result image is shown below:

[image: Result Image]

OpenCV tools like SURF, SIFT, ORB detects only one occurrence of the object in an image. Can you suggest some papers or tools to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there are multiple techniques to detect multiple instances of the same object in an image.

The most primitive way to do that is **template matching**. So you create a database of training images at multiple scales and rotations to be able to detect such objects in varying conditions. But there are many techniques that are better than such legacy technique.

Some other techniques uses texture features that is invariant over scale, rotation, or both. For example, GLCM, LBP, HOG, SIFT, ORB and others.

Your statement `OpenCV tools like SURF, SIFT, ORB detects only one occurrence of the object in an image.` needs more enhancement.

The listed tools are not intended to detect objects but they are means to extract texture features.
You are the one to adjust them to detect multiple objects.

There is a more fine way to solve your problem. It seems that all of your objects that are required to be detected contains the text `TASSAY`.
you can easily extract that text using a group of `morphological operations` and then using a blob detector detect the location of the text.
After returning the text, it can be easily to measure the text location.
The object bounding box can be easily inferred from the text location.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to adjust feature extract tools to detect multiple objects? Furthermore, there will also be other fine-grained images, TASSAY was only one example of the objects.

Comment: Some object detectors stop when finding the target object. Programmatically, the object detector can be adjusted to not stop when detecting an object and continue detecting more objects if any. For example, this link http://angeljohnsy.blogspot.com/2013/07/face-detection-matlab-code.html contains a MATLAB code that is adjusted to detect multiple faces.